# Реализация функции TryStrToBool

Tags: delphi

Собственно интересует, как корректно организовать работу функции `TryStrToBool` в Delphi 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А где то так

```
function TryStrToBool(s:string; default:boolean):boolean;
begin
  s := trim(s);
  if sametext(s, 'true') then result := true
  else if sametext(s, 'false') then result := false
  else result := default;
end;
```